# AppEngine Cloud EndPoint 404 Not Found with version 2 of my App

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have deployed a new version of my App that contains a new cloud endpoint.

I have made the new version the default version.
I have even deleted the old version (version 1).

- If I try to hit `https://<myappid>.appspot.com/_ah/api/` then I get a
  404 Not Found.
- If I try to hit `https://2-dot-<myappid>.appspot.com/_ah/api/` then
  my request gets served.

It's been a full 24 hours since I uploaded version 2. And more than an hour since I marked version 2 as default and deleted version 1, but I'm still getting the 404.

I don't want to ship my client explicitly pointing to `2-dot-<myappid>` as this locks the client to a particular version.

Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: what is the API root?

Comment: How did you change the default version? Was it via Cloud Console or App Engine Admin Console?

Comment: Cloud Console. But if I go to AppEngine Console (I thought it has been superceeded by Cloud Console?), version 2 is the only version and it is marked as the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Console currently doesn't automatically update Endpoints when changing app versions. You need to use the old App Engine Admin Console to make it update. So, I suggest trying switching versions to another version and switching back immediately. It should fix it for you.

1. Upload a new major version of your app. This can be identical to your current default version, which just the version name changed.
2. Visit the [App Engine Admin Console](https://appengine.google.com/) and select your project.
3. Click Versions.
4. Change the default version to the one you just deployed.
5. Change the default version back to the one it just was.

At this point, the default domain should be working for you.

Comment: can you provide a set of steps on how to achieve that?

Comment: I've tried this, but no luck. Has it worked for anyone?

Comment: @JudeOsborn: Cloud Console should actually update Endpoints now, so if you are unable to to get Endpoints working, it is likely something else. I suggest checking your app logs to look for requests to `BackendService.getApiConfigs` and starting a new question if you still need help.

Comment: Thanks, Saiyr. Nothing in my logs with BackendService.getApiConfigs. Also, endpoints do work on one version, but not the other (even with identical code). Conversely, if we upload different code to the one working version, all is fine. However, if I change versions, that's when endpoints stop working (regardless of what code is uploaded). I'll start a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

how about trying **"https://xandar-wordgame.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer"**,it may redirect the page to api-explorer where you can explore your api.

Others: 
I've also encountered the same problem. but then I realized I have not changed the javascript code that load the api client. I changed the **version in java annotation** , but forgot to change the gapi.client.load(_apiName, **_version**, _your_call_back_function,_apiRoot) in web client .
Hope it will help.

Comment: I think you're referring to the API version, not the App Engine version. Those are two separate things. Or am I misunderstanding?